# How to label axes in fipy.Viewer?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fipy

What would be the easiest way to label the x and y axes of a FiPy viewer? I specifically use the `fipy.viewers.matplotlibViewer.matplotlib2DGridContourViewer.Matplotlib2DGridContourViewer`. I tried giving the the parameter `xlabel="some string"` but that obviously didn't work because that class doesn't have that parameter. Then I saw that it can take a `matplotlib.figure.Axes` object as a parameter, but to create one, I would have to have an existing `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object and so everything is intertwining and I'm lost in documentations with such a seemingly simple goal. Is there some way to add labels simply by giving the Viwer a specific parameter?

Also I looked at the custom Viewer creation examples but I'm not that good in Python, so I would appreciate a detailed solution if I have to take that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MatplotlibViewer` classes have an `.axes` property, which you can use, e.g.,

```py
viewer = fp.MatplotlibViewer(...)
viewer.axes.set_xlabel("some string")
```

[No, this isn't documented anywhere](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/781).

The `axes=` argument is for cases where you have a complicated/custom presentation that you want FiPy to render into, but, as you've discovered, it's a lot of overhead if you're not already doing that.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's nice to see that FiPy has active and helpful developers :)